# spark - hadoop argument

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I am running both hadoop and spark and I want to use files from hdfs as an argument on spark-submit, so I made a folder in hdfs with the files 
eg. /user/hduser/test/input
and I want to run spark-submit like this:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --master spark://admin:7077 ./target/scala-2.10/test_2.10-1.0.jar hdfs://user/hduser/test/input
```

but I cant make it work, what's the right way to do it?

the error I am getting is :

> WARN FileInputDStream: Error finding new files
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Do you have any error ?

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: can you show, how did you read the files ?

Comment: val stream = ssc.textFileStream(args(0))

Comment: are you trying to read streaming data ?

Comment: Do you want to read properties file through it ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are able to access HDFS from Spark code, If yes then you need to add following line of code in your Scala import.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles
```

then in your code add following lines

```
var hadoopConf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()
var fileSystem = FileSystem.get(hadoopConf)
var path = new Path(args(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

actually the problem was the path. I had to use hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser/...